# AS3 Error reporting from event callback

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, actionscript, asynchronous, event-handling

I have been experimenting with supplying better debugging information when an error happens in asynchronous code in AS3.

As an example of the poor error reporting be default, take the case where I force a null pointer in a Timer callback ([github gist](https://gist.github.com/1151128)), I get the following stacktrace back on the console:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Function/<anonymous>()[/[path-to-source-file]/TestClass.as:14]
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

This tells me very little about how the timer callback actually links to my code.

The question is: How can I get information about what code created the callback?

I have added one of my solutions below. I'm interested to see if this can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to pre-create an Error object in the consumer "thread"/"scope"

```
        var errorInConsumerScope:Error = new Error()

        var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1)
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, internalCallback)
        timer.start()

        function internalCallback(e:TimerEvent):void 
        {
            try
            {
                // do something that could cause an error
            }
            catch (e:Error)
            {
                errorInConsumerScope.message = e.message
                throw errorInConsumerScope
            }
        }
```

This now gives me the stacktrace back into my calling code:

```
Error: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at TestClass()[/[path-to-source-file]/TestClass.as:10]
    at Main()[/[path-to-source-file]/Main.as:9]
```

The complete gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/1151146)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing.

[The doc to `Error.getStackTrace()` says](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html#getStackTrace%28%29):

> Returns the call stack for an error as a string at the time of the
>   error's construction

According to this, the stacktrace works as expected. The error is constructed in your event handler which is called by the timer tick event.

In your second example you create the error to be dispatched in the constructor of the TestClass. So your stacktrace will show the chain up to the TestClass constructor.

Comment: That's the point of the solution, so Errors are pretty handy things if they are created at the right moment ;)

Comment: You register the same listener function from several locations. Your solution will create an (empty) error for each listener registration, when I understand right what your are going to do. Empty objects are not actually what we want. The cleanest solution I see is to use different callbacks for different clients so that the Flash error can be easily matched to the listeners registration context.

Comment: It's extremely easy to lose the ability to trace back to the creator. All you need to do is have one level of indirection from your code (as in the example) and your clueless as to where the creating call came from.

Comment: @Brian I fail to see why you need to generate a new error when the default error thrown is plenty. In your example posted in the question it even shows the line number. The stack trace was also doing its job. However, in your answer the error thrown doesn't tell me what line the error is truly on. Maybe it is just me and I have seen way to maybe error stack traces.

Comment: @The_asMan in real world cases, the problem is not always as straightforward as a null pointer, the problem is possibly caused by arguments supplied by the creator of the TestClass. In that case it is much more valuable to see who created the TestClass than which part of the flash player sub system called the callback

Answer (score 0):

You probably ask for a general solution. I would go with unit tests and proper debugging using  breakpoints and object inspection. But here another idea:

TestClass:

```
package {
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class TestClass {
        public function TestClass(userCallback : Function, fail : Function) {
            var timer : Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, internalCallback);
            timer.start();

            function internalCallback(e : TimerEvent):void {
                try {
                    var nullProperty : String;
                    nullProperty.length;
                } catch (e:Error) {
                    fail();
                    return;
                }
                userCallback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        public function Main() {
            new TestClass(
                function() : void { trace('Call me back when your done.'); },
                function() : void { throw new Error('Something went wrong.'); }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception fault: Error: Something went wrong.
    at Function/<anonymous>()[Main.as:8]
    at Function/TestClass/$construct/internalCallback()[TestClass.as:16]
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this solution still only tells the story from the point of view of the Timer/tick() function. Tick is called from the browser/flash player potentially long after the source of the error has gone out of scope. What I'm interested in is solutions that start the scope-chain/stack-trace at Main.

Comment: The `fail()` method is a closure and maintains its context as long as there is a reference on it. You can remove the instance of `Main`, but it will not be garbage collected since there is a reference on a closure that needs the context of `Main`. Could you please check this?

Comment: The clojure is not the issue, it's true that the clojure holds scope etc. But variable scope is not the issue. My question relates to the stack trace given when an error occurs. In async code the stack trace begins at Timer/tick(), but that says nothing about who created the actual class or function. I'm interested in a solution that shows me who actually created the Timer from the point of view of the Main class. The fail() method is created in Main but called from the browsers event queue thread. so when it throws an Error the stack trace will be shown from the browsers point of view.

Comment: In short: most of the time I'm not interested in the browsers point of view, I want to know: what part of my code created the thing that failed.